# JavaScript: Change All Values of Deeply nested object given path

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JavaScript Object like this:

```
const Obj = {
  level1_1: "Value1",
  level1_2: "Value2",
  level1_3: "Value3",
  level1_4: "Value4",
  level1_5: {
    level2_1: {
      level3_1: { level4_1:1, level4_2:2, level4_3:3, level4_4:4 },
      level3_2: { level4_a:1, level4_b:2, level4_c:3, level4_d:4 } 
    },
    level2_2: {
      level3_1: { level4_5:1, level4_6:2, level4_7:3, level4_8:4 },
      level3_2: { level4_e:1, level4_f:2, level4_g:3, level4_h:4 } 
    }
  }
};
```

I want to change the `values` of all the `keys` inside level1_5.level2_1.Level3_1 object (ie. all level4) dynamically but not other values.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? Do you have an example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: What I meant was through code. Maybe iterating over it or something. I mostly found similar questions with objects inside nested arrays.

Comment: there is only one `Obj.level1` you can't have multiple of the same key, please improve your question

Comment: Thanks. Changed my question.

Comment: i saw that u already found ur answer.. is it ok if i just pop in a `forEvery` function i made? it imitates the commonly known `forEach` in arrays but for Objects.. going down every level(can take circulars).. takes in 2 arguments; an object and a function to handle the data.. this function is given 3 arguments.. the current element, that element's parent, and the level of depth where the current element is

Comment: You say dynamically, but you don't specify how you want to do it. For example, if you have an array of keys for the levels, you can write an iterative function that tries each key in sequence and stops if one is not found. Also, your question is not clear: you say "all level4", but your example does not include "Level3_2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the object attributes recursively while keeping track of the remaining path properties, if reached the last one and it exists, you can then change all the `values`:

```js
const Obj = {
  level1_1: "Value1",
  level1_2: "Value2",
  level1_3: "Value3",
  level1_4: "Value4",
  level1_5: {
    level2_1: {
      level3_1: { level4_1:1, level4_2:2, level4_3:3, level4_4:4 },
      level3_2: { level4_a:1, level4_b:2, level4_c:3, level4_d:4 } 
    },
    level2_2: {
      level3_1: { level4_5:1, level4_6:2, level4_7:3, level4_8:4 },
      level3_2: { level4_e:1, level4_f:2, level4_g:3, level4_h:4 } 
    }
  }
};

function getUpdatedObject (obj = {}, path = [], newVal) {
  const targetLevel = path.length;
  return (function setValuesOfPath (obj, path, newVal, currentLevel = 1) {
    if(currentLevel === targetLevel && path.length === 1) {
      const target = obj[path[0]];
      if(target) Object.keys(target).forEach(key => target[key] = newVal);
    }
    for (var property in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (typeof obj[property] === "object") {
          if(property === path[0]) path.shift();
          setValuesOfPath(obj[property], path, newVal, currentLevel+1);
        }
      }
    }
    return obj
  }(obj, path, newVal));
}

console.log(getUpdatedObject(Obj, ["level1_5", "level2_1", "level3_1"], "a"));
```

Using `lodash`:

```js
let Obj = {
  level1_1: "Value1",
  level1_2: "Value2",
  level1_3: "Value3",
  level1_4: "Value4",
  level1_5: {
    level2_1: {
      level3_1: { level4_1:1, level4_2:2, level4_3:3, level4_4:4 },
      level3_2: { level4_a:1, level4_b:2, level4_c:3, level4_d:4 } 
    },
    level2_2: {
      level3_1: { level4_5:1, level4_6:2, level4_7:3, level4_8:4 },
      level3_2: { level4_e:1, level4_f:2, level4_g:3, level4_h:4 } 
    }
  }
};

const setValuesOfPath = (obj = {}, path = [], newVal) => {
  const target = _.get(obj, path.join('.'));
  if(target) Object.keys(target).forEach(key => target[key] = newVal);
  return obj;
}

console.log(setValuesOfPath(Obj, ["level1_5", "level2_1", "level3_1"], "a"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all i dont think you have an object with the same key multiple time. I assume its just to showcase different properties. If you like to keep the object immutable you can do it this way: (but it depends on your usecase).

*Not 100% sure what you mean with dynamically?!*

```html
 Obj = {
       level1:"Value1",
       level11:"Value2",
       level12:"Value3",
       level13:"Value4",
       level14:{
                level2:{
                       level3:{
                               level4:Number,
                               level4:Number,
                               level4:Number,
                               level4:Number,
                              } 
                       }
                },
        }
 
 Obj = {
  ...Obj
  level14: {
    ...Obj.level14
    level2: {
      ...Obj.level14.level2
      level3: {
        level4: <your new number>
        level41: <your new number>
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This method works great. I was wondering If there was a way to iterate through all level 4 objects inside the desired level3 & level2 etc and change the values (Maybe multiply it by -1)